# Create materialized view with non-atomic refresh?

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

According to documents, non-atomic refresh of a materialized view uses truncate instead of delete in complete refresh. Is there any way to say oracle to use truncate instead of delete when creating a materialized view ?

Comment: You'll need to use atomic_refresh=>false as Frank Schmitt describes.  This is also why I do NOT setup a refresh schedule in the mat view creation itself (START WITH/NEXT syntax).  Stick with dbms_scheduler to setup refresh schedule, calling dbms_mview.refresh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no method that I'm aware of - you have to explicitly call dbms_mview.refresh with atomic => false:

```
begin
  dbms_mview.refresh( 'EMP_MV' , atomic_refresh => FALSE );
end;
```

**EDIT:** Unless you're using Oracle 9.2 or earlier - these versions perform a non-atomic refresh by default.

Comment: Obviously, this has not changed with 11.2g. You have to create the job yourself.